# How to add threading to a for loop in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm trying to write a raytracer in Rust. I'm having difficulty getting the for loops to run in parallel. I'm not sure where the problem is, but I can't seem to get anything on the screen. Is this the correct approach or am I completely heading in the wrong direction?

I've tried running the for loops without multi-threading and it does correctly produce output. I've also added loggers to the consumer loop and I'm getting the correct values as well. It just doesn't seem to update the window.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Pixel {
    pub x: usize,
    pub y: usize,
    pub color: Vec3,
}
```

```rust
let mut buffer : Vec<u32> = vec![0; WIDTH * HEIGHT];
let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel()

for x in 0..HEIGHT {
   let tx_t = tx.clone();
   thread::spawn(move || {
      for y in 0..WIDTH {
         let mut color = cast_ray(x, y); // returns vec3
         let pixel = Pixel { x: x, y: y, color: color };
         tx_t.send(pixel).unwrap();
      }
   });
}

for received in rx {
   buffer[received.x * WIDTH + received.y] = received.color.x << 16 | received.color.y << 8 | received.color.z;
}

while window.is_open() && !window.is_key_down(Key::Escape) {
   window.update_with_buffer(&buffer).unwrap();
}
```

I'm expecting a few spheres or color to appear on the screen, but it's just black.

Comment: Have you taken a look into [async / await](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/03_async_await/01_chapter.html) and usage of std::Future ?

Comment: The code we see seems to build the buffer. Maybe your problem is just that it's slow. Are you aware that you don't display anything before the computation is finished ? If you want to display while computing you need to draw **in** the `for received in rx` loop.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Oh wow. You're right. I didn't realize it would be this much slower than a non-threaded loop, but after I move the drawing inside the `for received in rx` loop, I could see the progress. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should have a look at crossbeam. This would also make it easier to deal with several types of events at the same time. And you should probably not redraw the whole every pixel (depends on what's in the hidden code)

Comment: Note that threads in Rust are OS threads, not lightweight green threads like you may be used to if you're coming from a language like Go. Spawning a thread per row of pixels is likely going to cause more overhead than speedup. Instead, you should look into using a threadpool to divide the work up over a smaller number of threads - [`rayon`](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon) is an excellent library for this. `crossbeam` also provides some useful utilities, like a more performant `channel` than the one in `std`.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. Your code is not syntactically valid and we can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, *otherwise* in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!